# WiFi port turns off randomly in Blaupunkt Cape Town 945

Tags: wi-fi, tethering, router

I use Blaupunkt Cape Town 945 all-in-one system in my car. That is audio, DVB-T, reversing camera, navigation, blue-tooth for phone etc, etc. This unit based on Android 4.1.1 Firmware version is 1011403920001_SW_20151223 + root + Google Play, the latest available.
My problem is that WiFi interface turns off always when WiFi source (like my phone with GSM/LTE to WiFi router tethering facility) disappears. It is important for me because I use it for example for on-line navigation, traffic jam info and so on. From my point of view - it is s/w bug. I want to find out workaround.
Is any possibility to keep WiFi interface always on even after lost of WiFi source? Maybe additional application must be installed from Google Play. Can anybody recommend me such app?
Blaupunkt support does not answer me for my question. So maybe somebody on this forum?
This unit is mounted and powered from car accu. So power saving facilities are not important for me.

Comment: other option is install app "Best WiFi Keeper".

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved problem. Generally it is work around not real solving problem but it is enough. What is needed:

- root unit with init.d support (included in original firmware)
- busybox installed (from Play Store)
- crond installed (from Google Play)

Add line in cron configuration:

```
* * * * * /system/bin/svc wifi enable
```

Thats all!